# Get error message from JsonClient

Tags: javascript, node.js, restify

I created a JsonClient with node.js restify.

```
var json_client = restify.createJsonClient({
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8888',
    version: '~1.0'
});

json_client.get('/test?list=' + test_list, function (err, req, res, test_list_results) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('err: ' + err);
            }
            else
            {
                console.log('success');
            }
}
```

I deliberately turn off the webserver to see if an error was captured. No error was captured. The code inside `json_client.get` was skipped. How can some form of error be detected?

EDIT: I discovered something while experimenting after getting answer from Quentin. If I leave out `connectTimeout`, an error message does appear. Just need to wait for seconds later.

Comment: Are `http_client` and `json_client` different? Typo?

Comment: Sorry, the original code was correct. Made mistake when copying code to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `connectTimeout: someNumber` to your options. (Or possibly just wait long enough).

Having done that, I get:

> ```
> %  node tet.js
> err: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8888
> ```

Comment: With all the other options like url and version.

Comment: I looked at https://www.npmjs.com/package/restify-clients

It advises `The default is not to set a connectTimeout, so you end up with the node.js socket defaults.` Is that sound advice? Without connectTimeout, I get no error msg.

Comment: I check http://restify.com/#jsonclient It doesn't say the time unit in `connectTimeout: someNumber`. Is `someNumber` in ms or seconds?

Comment: I discovered something. If I leave out `connectTimeout`, an error message does appear. Just need to wait for seconds later.